# Why is .then() not returning the values expected from JavaScript fetch?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

So the question is pretty straightforward. Why does this work:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/vampaynani/repos")
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((repos) => {
    console.log(repos);
    this.setState({ repos });
  });
```

But this does not:

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/vampaynani/repos").then((repos) => {
      var r = repos.json();
      this.setState({ repos: r });
    });
```

Here is the sandbox link for it: [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/fetch-example-forked-uebqh2?file=/src/index.js:227-374)

Maybe my understanding is wrong, but in my eyes these look to be doing the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `repos.json()` is a promise that needs to be resolved (awaited) before.

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/vampaynani/repos").then(async (repos) => {
      var r = await repos.json();
      this.setState({ repos: r });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `repos.json()` returns a **Promise**. It's an async function.